# PR-ASK modulation

Tags: modulation

I am trying to envision the circuit which will allow me to get PR-ASK modulation. Fundamentally there are two ways to produce the PR-ASK;

1. Toggling digital data between +- V and mixing it with CW at Mixer stage, OR
2. managing to introduce a phase shift of 180 degrees at each transition of digital data.

Now my questions how do I realize this in real life? I am using MCU to generate digital data (data rate 100 kbps) and feed it to Transceiver IC ([S2LP](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/s2-lp.pdf)) via GPIO and then mix it with CW (866 MHz) generated from S2LP at the mixer stage. My MCU is capable of toggling digital data between + V and 0 V.

IS there any other way by which I can achieve PR-ASK using S2LP? Like using some of the values of the registers which are generating ASK modulation and other modulation types (FSK, 2-FSK, 4-FSK)?

Comment: Numbers are needed. What is the carrier wave frequency and what is the data rate. Those numbers can determine a likely solution.

Comment: I have added the numbers, the CW would be 866 MHz and a datarate of 100 kbps.

Comment: I'd use a mixer module - try [mini-circuits](https://www.minicircuits.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do what you got in mind.

---

But, anyway, try this:

use the S2LP internal ASK/OOK modulation an then modify the FIR filter in order to shape the carrier according to your needs.

After that, have the S2LP transceiver handle packets transmissions and receptions.

Comment: I was thinking on this line too. Using the FIR filter, I can certainly tune/shape the bandwidth. But I am sure this wont allow me to see the phase reversal at the data boundary in the time domain.
BTW, is it possible to use CONST_MAPregister in S2LP to achieve phase shift with ASK modulation? Or this facility is only for FSK modulation?

Comment: I don't know. Try posting the question on the ST wireless forum or contact your local FAE. I strongly though that the S2LP transceiver is that flexible.